# Prevent two processes Android Studio initializes when building Android applications from executing

Tags: android, process, android-gradle-plugin, ram, android-studio-3.0

After Android Studio applying changes for about an hour, my computer starts to freeze. By checking Task Manager I see two processes consuming nearly 1 gigabyte of RAM, not to count Android Studio itself that consumes another 1.5 gigabytes or more. The result is almost 100% of my RAM memory being used and a computer struggling to even move the cursor. It already happened to reach the point I needed to force a restart by pressing and holding the power button.

[image]

The image above shows the beginning only. I would like to prevent these two processes from executing. I don't know what they are for, but killing them does not cause anything unusual, only it keeps my computer and Android Studio working normally and I continue to be happy.